# How to Change Grouping of Radio Buttons in Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

The app I am trying to make needs a few info in the beggining, these questions include a radio button I have four radio buttons in the same frame and I want to change the grouping so there are two questions being answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two GroupBoxes (frame) or Panels (no frame).  GroupBox is best, it shows the user what radio buttons belong together.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use combo boxes (drop-down listboxes) instead?

Comment: maybe that would work better thanks for you really quick reply